# Is there any open source ISO 11703 java implementation?

Tags: java, standards, medical

I'm looking for an java implementation of the ISO 11073 standard (Health informatics - Point of care medical device communication), especially the Medical package of it.

Comment: So be more precise I need a standard (because it should interact with 3rd party components) to store medical data like weight or blood pressure in a object oriented Java database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My intuition and google tell me, there isn't one. The usage is pretty limited, companies can make really a lot of money with implementing this standard and I doubt, that providers of medical equipment would rely on an open source implementation of a standard to *exchange and evaluate vital signs data between different medical devices, as well as remote control these devices*.

There is the eclipse project [Open Healthcare Framework (OHF)](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project_summary.php?projectid=technology.ohf). Maybe those experts can tell you more.

Comment: It seems that the OHF project is dead. Their last committer teleconference was in 2007 and also their last release.

Comment: @Steven Mohr - Oh, I didn't know. Just remembered from some years ago that there was a project proposal.

Comment: The OHF was integrated in the Open Health Tools. But it seems that this project isn't that active too.

Answer (score 2):

Antidote (http://oss.signove.com/index.php/Antidote:_IEEE_11073-20601_stack) is written in C but it has Java bindings for Android, so it could be useful.